# Mysql - procedure to get next auto increment

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, auto-increment

I'm having some problems writing a stored procedure to get next value of Auto Incremented column. I want to be able to pass a table name and have the value returned to a specified variable.

The procedure is as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Find_last_AI(
        IN table_name VARCHAR(255),
        OUT last_AI INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
    INTO last_AI
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MySchema'
    AND   TABLE_NAME = table_name
    LIMIT 1;
END;
```

The problem is, after I call the function like this:

```
CALL Find_last_AI('MyTable', @out);    
SELECT @out;
```

I get the same wrong result - a numeric value (5) no matter what the table input is. The thing is, when I execute the code as a query the results yield correct values.

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MySchema'
    AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name'
    LIMIT 1;
```

It seems that I'm forgetting something in the procedure itself, but I can't see it ?

Comment: You use `"` around the column name and you really get the correct result? Can't really believe that.

Comment: Why, why, why? Oh, the humanity.

Comment: Sorry the server is ANSI_QUOTES enabled. Edited the " anyway, does not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried myself like below and it worked fine.

```
set @tabname = 'tab';

    SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
    INTO @incre
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tabname
    LIMIT 1;

select @incre;
```

Also Good to mention that, using the query above you will get the next (future) `auto_increment` value (nothing but, present value + 1).

**EDIT:**

Finally got it; problem is with `LIMIT 1` in your query. Try the below code and it's guaranteed to work fine (TESTED). Also, don't use any reserved word as variable name.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Find_last_AI(IN tname VARCHAR(255), OUT last_AI INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
    INTO last_AI
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'test'
    AND   TABLE_NAME = tname;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Run the procedure like

```
CALL Find_last_AI('test3', @last_AI);    
SELECT @last_AI;
```

Comment: Thanks for input, but it is not that. I removed the quotes from OP as they are not really needed, but I probably should have mentioned that the server is running with ANSI_QUOTES enabled.

Comment: @Feek.404, I think I got it. see edited answer again.

Comment: That was my mistake trying to make the code rid of foreign table names, sorry. The second code you posted works fine. **But** when I define the procedure and then call it, the results are somehow different. Maybe I'm calling it wrong like this: `CALL Find_last_AI('tabname', @out); ` and then `SELECT @out;`

Comment: @Feek.404, NO, you are calling it correctly. But are you passing the table name correctly? I doubt so. I have no means of testing it by creating a proc; tried creating a proc in SQL fiddle but that's not working.

Comment: That might be the issue, but so far when calling the procedure I explicitly pass the table name as `'table_name'` (as in first post). I thought that it should work to pass it like this ?

Comment: @Feek.404, Finally don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I'm calling it the same way as in your example (with a string containing the name of the actual table). I honestly have no idea why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Feek.404, You made me install MySQL. check edited answer and now it will work absolutely fine.

Comment: It does indeed work! Thanks very much, probably saved me some more trouble!

Answer (score 0):

to add the value auto_increment you must do it within the procedure, getting the last id and add 1, is a somewhat valid solution I leave SP:

```
#SP 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE set_Estados(in Estado VARCHAR(45))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE validar INT;
        DECLARE ID INT;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO validar FROM table_name WHERE table_row=Estado;
        if validar = 0 THEN
            SELECT (max(estados_id)+1) INTO ID FROM table_name limit 1;
            #the value estados_id its a auto_increment value, just call to add the value...
            INSERT INTO table_name(estados_id,estados_estado) VALUES(ID,Estado);
            CALL get_Estados(); #SP that show all data...
        ELSE
            SELECT CONCAT('El Estado: ',Estado,' ya existe.') ESTADO;
        END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL set_Estados('Activo');
```