# Couldn't get the call addusers procedure to work for testing because of auto increment

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have problem with Addusers procedure because I add UserID as out for auto increment since I basically want to pass:

```
CALL addusers
(

  'Rory',
   'Covertry',
   '5566',
   'rory@gmail.com'
   '1234',
   'U'
)
```

I'm expected to insert the data but I ended getting an error like this.

"Error

```
SQL query:

    CALL addusers
    (

    'Rory',
       'Covertry',
       '5566',
       'rory@gmail.com'
       '1234',
       'U'
    )
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   1318 - Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE construction.addusers; expected 7, got 5"

Here's my stored procedure for

```
 addusers



DELIMITER go
Create procedure Addusers(
  Out UserID int(11),
 IN FirstName varchar(30),
 IN LastName varchar(30),
 IN Password varchar(30),
 IN EmailAddress varchar(30),
 IN Salt varchar(40),
 IN RoleID varchar(1))
BEGIN
insert into users(

FirstName,
 LastName ,
 Password ,
 EmailAddress ,
 Salt ,
 RoleID 
 )
Values
(
FirstName,
 LastName ,
 Password ,
 EmailAddress ,
 Salt ,
 RoleID 
);
set UserID = AUTO_INCREMENT;  

End
go
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: There is a little `?` icon on the edit dialog. Click it and then look at `Advanced Help` to find out how to use the editor to format things correctly

Comment: [Mysql - procedure to get next auto increment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23716973/3814721) might be helpful..-

Comment: I actually look at it then I try   CALL addusers
    (

    'Rory',
       'Covertry',
       '5566',
       'rory@gmail.com'
       '1234',
       'U'
    ) select @UserId; but I got an error that says:" MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''rory',
       'Rory',
       'Covertry',
       '5566',
       'rory@gmail.com'
       '1234',
       'U' at line 3"

Comment: DELIMITER go
Create procedure registerusers(
  Out UserID int(11),
 IN FirstName varchar(30),
 IN LastName varchar(30),
 IN Password varchar(30),
 IN EmailAddress varchar(30),
 IN Salt varchar(40),
 IN RoleID varchar(1))
BEGIN
insert into users(
 
FirstName,
 LastName ,
 Password ,
 EmailAddress ,
 Salt ,
 RoleID 
 )
Values
(
FirstName,
 LastName ,
 Password ,
 EmailAddress ,
 Salt ,
 RoleID 
)
set UserID = AUTO_INCREMENT;  

End
go
DELIMITER ;

Answer (score 0):

You must use `last_insert_id()` instead of `AUTO_INCREMENT` reserved word, and put all 7 parameters when you do a call:

```
DELIMITER go
Create procedure Addusers(
  Out UserID int(11),
 IN FirstName varchar(30),
 IN LastName varchar(30),
 IN Password varchar(30),
 IN EmailAddress varchar(30),
 IN Salt varchar(40),
 IN RoleID varchar(1))
BEGIN
insert into users(

FirstName,
 LastName ,
 Password ,
 EmailAddress ,
 Salt ,
 RoleID 
 )
Values
(
FirstName,
 LastName ,
 Password ,
 EmailAddress ,
 Salt ,
 RoleID 
);
set UserID = last_insert_id();  

End
go
DELIMITER ;
```

To get the `OUT` parameter you must use a session variable like this:

```
set @new_id = null;
call addusers(@new_id,'Rory','Covertry','5566','rory@gmail.com','1234','U' );
select @new_id; -- contains the inserted id
```